# Pycharm documentation template

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

Pycharm presents me with the following template for a docstring:

```
    """

    :param var1: 
    :param var2: 
    """
```

for a function `def func(var1,var2)`.

Why does Pycharm uses this template? Is there some PEP or (unwritten) convention that this is good style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Pycharm uses [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html). The template can be changed in Settings → Tools → Python Integrated Tools. Currently, there are 5 styles available: Plain, Epytext, reStructuredText, NumPy, Google.

[PEP 287](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/) proposes reStructuredText as a standard format for docstrings.